# Django states pytz isn't installed but it is

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm a noob with django and python and related issues. So factor that into my question.

I am using a virtual environment to work on Django. Working from a tutorial from a book.

In order to install pytz specified the location of python in my virtual environment:

```
/Users/username/django/my_env/bin/python -m pip install pytz
```

It seemed to successfully install. However I get this error in Django when I try to create a post:

> This query requires pytz, but it isn't installed.

Pytz is installed. I attempted to install it within my virtual environment while specifying the specific python library it needed to use.

**A couple of factors that are probably related.** When I installed/created my virtual environment, it automatically set it up with Python2.7. I didn't want that so I added Python 3.4 to my virtual environment. So there are now two Python versions installed.

I don't know if I'm supposed to remove one. I don't know why it automatically installed 2.7 either (the tutorial doesn't clarify this process). I was hoping that installing 3.4 would replace 2.7.

Pytz does appear to be a package installed in 3.4. So what am I supposed to do in order to use Python 3.4 in my virtual environment and Pytz?

Comment: try `django-admin shell` (or `python manage.py shell`) and then `import pytz`. Does it work?

Comment: How did you "add python 3.4" to the existing virtual environment? The way to do it is to start from scratch with the version of python you want to use. Something like this should work: `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>`. You then have to `pip install` all packages in the new environment as well.

Comment: I don't recall how I installed 3.4 into the existing environment. I may have found some random tutorial on how to do that. I will try to start from scratch. It does seem strange to have two versions there but as mentioned, my tutorial doesn't confront this issue.

Comment: You can use `virtualenv --help` to learn how it works. The flag `--clear` can be used to "start from scratch"

Comment: for python 3, I recommend using pyvenv and no more virtualenv

Comment: I'll take that into account. Thanks.